# Issues setting a hexadecimal value to a char variable for padding

Tags: c++, database, data-structures, alignment, padding

I'm having issues trying to set a `char` variable to a hexadecimal value.

I'm trying to implement a print function where I print the alignment of a structure. The "aa" is suppose to represent the padding, but I can't seem to set the variable in the default constructor.

Output that it should be

```
0x00: 00 00 00 00      
0x04: 00 aa aa aa
```

.h file

```
struct A
{
    int  a0;
    char a1;
    char pad0;
    char pad1;
    char pad2;
    A() {
        a0 = 0;
        a1 = 0;
        pad1 = 0xAA;
        pad2 = 0xAA;
    }
};
```

.cpp

```
Alignment::Alignment:Print(void *data)  
{
    int d {0 };
    for (int i = 0; i <2; ++i) {
        printf("\n0x%02x:", (d));
        d = d + 4;
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(data); ++j)
        {
            printf(" %.2x", (*((unsigned char*)data+j )));
        }
     }

}
```

Main

```
A *pa = new A;
```

Pa is passed into the function

My Output

```
0x00: 00 00 00 00
0x04: 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: What is your expected result, and how are you printing?

Comment: You are not initializing `pad0` in your constructor

Comment: @Chipster Im expecting to print the AA when ever it detects padding. But, im sure how to set that to the char variable.

Comment: How are you attempting to print. Could you add it to your question?

Comment: @Chipster yeah sorry about that i added it

Comment: No problem. Thanks.

Comment: Now, what do you mean by "detects padding"? Could you add a counter-part to "Output" called something like "Expected Output"? I think I might be able to understand you better that way. Also, please show the part of your code where you set up whatever you're passing to `data` and add it here.

Comment: @chipster i should rephrase that. Im trying to assign 0xaa to char pad so, that whenever its printing it will print aa.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your `Print` function. Some are "just" style, but they make fixing the real issue harder. (Also, you jumped to conclusions, possibly blinding you to the real issue.) First off, try to explain why the line

```
            printf(" %.2x", (*((unsigned char*)data+j )));
```

is supposed to do something different just because `i` and `d` changed. Neither of those variables are in this line, so you get the same output with each iteration of the outer loop. The problem is not in the setting of data, but in the reading of it. For each line of output, you print the first four bytes of data when you intended to print the next four bytes.

To get the next four bytes, you need to add `d` to the pointer, but this is problematic because you increased `d` earlier in this iteration. Better would be to have `d` keep the same value throughout each iteration. You could increase it at the end of the iteration instead of the middle, but even slicker might be to use `d` to control the loop instead of `i`.

Finally, a bit of robustness: your code uses the magic number `4` when increasing `d`, which only works if `sizeof(data)` is 4. Fragile. Better would be to use a symbolic constant for this magic value to ensure consistency. I'll set it explicitly to `4` since I don't see why the size of a pointer should impact how the pointed-to data is displayed.

```
Alignment::Alignment::Print(void *data)  
{
    constexpr int BytesPerLine = 4; // could use sizeof(void *) instead of 4
    const unsigned char * bytes = static_cast<unsigned char*>(data); // Taking the conversion out of the loop.

    for (int d = 0; d < 2*BytesPerLine; d += BytesPerLine) {
        printf("\n0x%02x:", (d));
        for (int j = 0; j < BytesPerLine; ++j)
        {
            printf(" %.2x", *(bytes + d + j)); // Add d here!
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: How would i go about making each of the pads come out as aa instead of 00?

Comment: @Jay The two that were set to `0xaa` do come out as `aa`, once you add `d` to the address whose contents you print out. See [example on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/636MzJH0Cz8wxeR8).

Comment: whenever i would try to set the pad to 0xaa and compile i would an warning saying the following would be treated as error. Should i make char pad Unsigned when i set it?

Comment: @Jay Yes, `unsigned` is appropriate for values that are to be treated as bit patterns rather than as numbers.